# Fail to install Grub2

Tags: grub2, 17.04

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 7000 with 16 GB RAM and 512 GB SSD.
I repartitioned and left 100 GB Unallocated for installing Linux.
Previously succeeded installing OpenSuse 42.3 beside Windows 10 after changing SSD from RAID to AHCI and Disabling Secure Boot.
Now I wish to install Ubuntu 17.04 and it seems to install like a dream with wifi support, but then fails to install Grub2 at the end.
I do not know how to get it to overwrite the old OpenSuse boot loader.
Can anyone please advise?  Thank you.

Comment: Please make sure you're booting the installation media in UEFI mode (and if manually partitioning - "something else" - make sure to also select the EFI partition but do not format, obviously). It doesn't need to override any bootloader, in UEFI bootloaders coexist in ESP (EFI System Partition).

Comment: It's too late to post an answer because you've moved on to Linux Miint, but here's the way to solve this problem. Make a Boot-Repair live USB or install Boot-Repair on a live USB. Install Ubuntu until the end skipping installing grub because the Ubuntu installer says that it can't install it. Reboot to Boot-Repair and run the recommend repair. Reboot to the Ubuntu installer and run it all the way through to the end. This time the Ubuntu installer will overwrite the grub that Boot-Repair installed with the default Ubuntu grub, and the Ubuntu installation will finish successfully.